# Как скрыть все элементы с атрибутом child больше 0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как скрыть все элементы с атрибутом `lvl` больше 0. Подскажите пожалуйста ))

Вот разметка:

```
<ul id="list_cat">
   <li>Корень каталога</li>
   <li lvl="0" parent="0" value="10">Hyndai</li>
   <li lvl="1" parent="10" value="154">Bosch ME17.9.11-12</li>
   <li lvl="2" parent="154" value="50">Elantra</li>
   <li lvl="3" parent="50" value="54">AКПП</li>
</ul>
```

с помощью jquery

Comment: что значит "атрибут child больше 0"?

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin прошу прощения, в данном случае атрибут lvl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#list_cat li').filter(function() {
    return  $(this).attr("lvl") > 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Спасибо ) Работает!

Answer (score 2):

Сначала нужно выбрать все элементы с таким атрибутом

```
$('#list_cat li[lvl]')
```

затем из набора выбрать только те, у которых нужное значение, с помощью [метода filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)

```
.filter(function(i,el){ return parseInt($(el).attr('lvl'),10) > 0; })
```

затем скрыть их с помощью [метода hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Пример в сборе

```js
$('#list_cat li[lvl]').filter(function(i, el) {
  return parseInt($(el).attr('lvl'), 10) > 0;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list_cat">
  <li>Корень каталога</li>
  <li lvl="0" parent="0" value="10">Hyndai</li>
  <li lvl="1" parent="10" value="154">Bosch ME17.9.11-12</li>
  <li lvl="2" parent="154" value="50">Elantra</li>
  <li lvl="3" parent="50" value="54">AКПП</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить массив `child` пройтись по нему с помощью `each` проверить значение `lvl` и если оно удовлетворяет вашему условию то применить к элементу `hide`